# How to use a secondary geometry in LABEL object

Tags: postgis, mapserver

I have a set of settlement features with two geometries: one is an outline polygon and another is a label point.

The features are fetched from a PostGIS db:

```
LAYER
    NAME "settlements"
    CONNECTIONTYPE postgis
    CONNECTION "user=x password=x dbname=x host=localhost"
    DATA "polygon_geom from (select id, name, polygon_geom, label_geom from settlements) as subquery using unique id"
```

The polygon_geom is then used in all CLASS STYLE and LABEL objects of this layer.

Is it possible to make the LABEL objects use the secondary label_geom geometry?

The only solution I've found was to setup a separate layer which gets that label_geom as the primary geometry. But is it possible to achieve it within one layer?

Comment: One layer has exactly one type (`line`/`point`/`polygon`).

Comment: Is there any tricky approach like ...just guessing... use a transformation javascript to get the point geom as attribute and return it back as geom?

Comment: MapServer takes a single geometry column from what you write in DATA. What's the problem with having two layers?

Comment: Performance. With two layers setup there will be two connections to the database and one and the same data row will be queried twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapServer use a single geometry column for a single layer, and expects all objects to have the same type (line/point/polygon).

It would be possible to use SQL's UNION ALL to combine two queries so that the objects are returned in a single column, but that would not be any simpler or more efficient than using two layers.

To make both layers use the same connection, use [connection pooling](https://mapserver.org/mapfile/layer.html#index-59):

```
PROCESSING "CLOSE_CONNECTION=DEFER"
```